# jquery waypoint animate each li fadeup

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-waypoints, animate.css

I'm trying to use jquery waypoint to do a fade on each li as i scroll down the page. I can't get it working for each li.

Here's the code:

```
  $('ul.animated li').each(function(){
    $(this).waypoint(function(){
      $(this).addClass('fadeInUp');
    },{
      offset:'100%'
    });
  });

<ul class="no-margin animated">
    <li><a href="/our-services/business-and-commercial-law.html">Business &amp; Commercial Law <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="/our-services/business-and-commercial-law/banking-and-finance.html">Banking &amp; Finance <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="/our-services/business-and-commercial-law/commercial-contracts-and-agreements.html">Commercial Contracts &amp; Agreements <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="/our-services/debt-recovery-and-insolvency.html">Debt Recovery &amp; Insolvency <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="/our-services/debt-recovery-and-insolvency/debt-recovery.html">Debt Recovery <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="/our-services/debt-recovery-and-insolvency/insolvency.html">Insolvency <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="/our-services/property-law.html">Property Law <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="/our-services/property-law/real-estate.html">Real Estate <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="/our-services/property-law/leases.html">Leases <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="/our-services/litigation-and-dispute-resolution.html">Litigation &amp; Dispute Resolution <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="/our-services/wills-and-estates.html">Wills &amp; Estates <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="/our-services/wills-and-estates/estate-planning-and-wills.html">Estate Planning &amp; Wills <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="/our-services/wills-and-estates/probate-and-estate-administration.html">Probate &amp; Estate Administration <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="/our-services/wills-and-estates/estate-litigation.html">Estate Litigation <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm not sure how to get it working, if anyone could help, that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using this:

```
$('ul.animated li').each(function(){
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.waypoint(function(){
      $el.addClass('fadeInUp');
    },{
      offset:'100%'
    });
  });
```